# Need to do bulk file upload in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little bit of an unusual situation I guess. I have a page for placing new orders and part of a new order is a variable (0-n) number of files that are to be uploaded and associated with the order on the back end. The user also needs to specify a description for each file.

I've used a couple jQuery upload plug-ins with great success, but in this case I'm not looking to upload a single file when the user hits "OK." What I really need to do is upload a file by passing a local path to some method that will do the upload.

Does anyone know of any plug-ins that do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Servers cannot access local (on client's browser) paths, but it is possible to upload multiple files using JavaScript. This article looks promising - http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax Uploader](http://ajaxuploader.com/download.htm) could be helpful? I believe it allows multiple uploads.